# Liferay: Using the roles configured in an external application

Tags: liferay

Whether liferay can use the roles/permissions that is configured outside liferay? The reason behind is that the legacy application have its own mechanism for user and role configuration.

Can any one please help me on this?

Regards
Vishal G

Answer (score 0):

Liferay does integrate with LDAP, should you configure it so, so that your LDAP directory holds the users and their roles etc. You can likely add some other code to interface with another user database, but I'd start with the LDAP environment, as you don't say what kind of technology you're talking about.

If it's homegrown, I'd consider either exporting to LDAP or taking the LDAP interface as blueprint for embedding your own solution.

Comment: Hi Olaf,

I should try out using LDAP interface to embed my own solution

Regards
Vishal G